# Using Tensorflow Neural Network in Gekko Model

Tags: python, gekko

I'm trying to use a trained Tensorflow neural network model to predict methane selectivity and then use gekko to minimize this. Whenever I try to use the model to make a prediction I get a IndexError. Any ideas on why that could be?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
from joblib import load
from gekko import ML
from gekko.ML import CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler

features = ['Oil T', 'Tmax', 'Recycle', 'Syngas', 'P', 'CH4 Comp']
features2 = ['Oil T', 'Tmax', 'Recycle', 'Syngas', 'P']

df = pd.read_csv('Training Set.csv').dropna()
df2 = pd.read_csv('Test Set.csv').dropna()
df3 = pd.read_csv('Aug4_6 Data.csv').dropna()

df = df[df['P']>19.8]
df = df[df['CH4 Comp']>5]
df = df[df['Syngas']<2.8]
df = df[df['Recycle']<40.075]

df2 = df2[df2['P']>20.02]
df2 = df2[df2['Oil T']<210.1]
df2 = df2[df2['Oil T']>209.91]
df2 = df2[df2['Recycle']>40.003]

df3 = df3[df3['P']>15.82]
df3 = df3[df3['CH4 Comp']>3]
df3 = df3[df3['Recycle']>23.95]

df3 = df3[['Oil T', 'Tmax', 'Recycle', 'Syngas', 'P', 'CH4 Comp', 'CH4 Selec']]
df4 = df.append(df3)
df4 = df4[['Oil T', 'Tmax', 'Recycle', 'Syngas', 'P', 'CH4 Selec']]

s = CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler(df4,features2,['CH4 Selec'])

from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('/Users/dallinlittlewood/Smart Systems')

m = GEKKO()
nt = 601
t = np.linspace(0,1000,nt)
m.time = t

Model = ML.Gekko_NN_TF(model,s.minMaxValues(),m)

## Reactor Properties
ρ_b = m.Const(value=0.8*1e6) #g/m3
D = m.Const(value=1.5/39.37) #m
L = m.Const(value=4*12/39.37) #m
Ac = m.Intermediate(np.pi/4*D**2) #m2
V = m.Intermediate(np.pi/4*D**2*L) #m3
W = m.Intermediate(Ac*L*ρ_b) #weight of catalyst, g
Cp = m.Const(value=53.89*74.93) #kJ/kg/K
Ua = m.Const(value=5e4)

## Syngas Feed
yco = m.Const(0.214)
yh2 = m.Const(0.46)
T0 = m.Const(value= 195 + 273.15) #K

## Kinetics
A = m.Const(value=3.32e7/60) #mol/g/s/atm^0.55
Ea = m.Const(value=93.8) #kJ/mol
ΔHr = m.Const(value=-165) #kJ/mol
R = m.Const(value=8.314e-3) #kJ/mol/K

## Manipulated Variables
Tc = m.MV(value=200+273.15,lb=195+273.15,ub=230+273.15)
P = m.MV(value=19.9,lb=17/1.01325,ub=24/1.01325) #atm
q = m.MV(value=2.5,lb=2,ub=6) #SLPM
Recycle = m.MV(value=40,lb=20,ub=50) #SLPM

F0 = m.Intermediate(q/0.082057/273.15/60) #mol/s
Fco = m.Intermediate(F0*yco) #mol/s

Tc.STATUS = 1
Tc.DCOST = 0

P.STATUS = 1
P.DCOST = 0

q.STATUS = 1
q.DCOST = 0

Recycle.STATUS = 1
Recycle.DCOST = 0

T = m.Var(value=196+273.15,lb=195+273.15,ub=215+273.15)

## Equations
Pco = m.Intermediate(P*yco)
Ph2 = m.Intermediate(P*yh2)
r_CO = m.Intermediate(A*m.exp(-Ea/R/T)*Pco**(-0.05)*Ph2**0.6)
#X_CO = m.Intermediate(W*r_CO/Fco)
m.Equation(T.dt() == (-ΔHr)*r_CO/Cp + Ua*(Tc - T)/ρ_b/Cp/V)

CH4_selec = Model.predict([Tc-273.15,T-273.15,Recycle,q,P])
```

I'm using CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler to scale the data and I'm using Gekko_NN_TF to load the Tensorflow NN. The error I keep getting is

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2ca486a260bc> in <module>
     96 m.Equation(T.dt() == (-ΔHr)*r_CO/Cp + Ua*(Tc - T)/ρ_b/Cp/V)
     97 
---> 98 CH4_selec = Model.predict([Tc-273.15,T-273.15,Recycle,q,P])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gekko/ML.py in predict(self, a, return_std)
    817                 aNext = feedforward(a_scaled,n,self.W,self.b)
    818             else:
--> 819                 aNext = feedforward(aNext,n,self.W,self.b)
    820         if return_std:
    821             aNextSigma = []

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gekko/ML.py in feedforward(a, n, W, b)
    780             a_len = self.layer_sizes[n+1]
    781             for i in range(a_len):
--> 782                 aNext.append(self.m.Intermediate(activation(self.m.sum(W[n].T[i] * a)+b[n][i])))
    783             return aNext
    784 

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about the trouble. The default number of outputs for the Gekko_NN_TF function is 2. I think your issue may be fixed by including n_output = 1 when using this function.

```
Model = ML.Gekko_NN_TF(model,s.minMaxValues(),m,n_output = 1)
```

Gekko_NN_TF was designed to provide a second output that gives an uncertainty prediction, but should not be required. Hopefully this solves your issue.