# Embedding multiple input multiple output neural networks into a GEKKO model

Tags: gekko

I have some questions regarding the application of the GEKKO machine learning library. I want to develop a neural network-based model predictive controller in GEKKO. The original system is modelled as a differential algebraic equation system. The neural network replaces the model equations of the original system. Apart from that, neither the objective function nor the bounds or the initial conditions will be changed. The original system with the model equations is being used in a closed-loop simulation model predictive controller successfully.

So far, I have found some examples of feedforward neural networks with a single output.

- [Why does Gekko_NN_TF add so many degrees of freedom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76992918/why-does-gekko-nn-tf-add-so-many-degrees-of-freedom)
- https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ml.html
- [Using Tensorflow Neural Network in Gekko Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069097/using-tensorflow-neural-network-in-gekko-model)

My questions are the following:

- Can ML.Gekko_NN_TF() and model.predict() be used for a multiple input multiple output network?
- Can they be used particularly for a (LSTM) recurrent neural network?
- Has anyone had experience trying something similar?

If this is not possible, how should I approach the task of embedding the recurrent neural network into GEKKO for the optimization?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of using TensorFlow / Scikit-learn Neural Networks, SVR, and GPR in Gekko from the documentation:

```py
def control1(model=[],returns=False,plot=True):
    global m

    m = GEKKO() # initialize gekko
    nt = 101
    m.time = np.linspace(0,2,nt)
    # Variables
    x1 = m.Var(value=1)
    x2 = m.Var(value=0)
    u = m.Var(value=0,lb=-1,ub=1)
    p = np.ones(nt) # mark final time point
    p[-1] = 1.0
    final = m.Param(value=p)
    # Equations
    m.Equation(x1.dt()==u)
    if(model == []):
        f = 0.5*x1**2
    else:
        if(model[0] == 'GPR'):
            f = Gekko_GPR(model[1],m).predict([x1])
        elif(model[0] == 'SVR'):
            f = Gekko_SVR(model[1],m).predict([x1])
        elif(model[0] == 'NNSK'):
            f = Gekko_NN_SKlearn(model[1],model[2],m).predict([x1])
        elif(model[0] == 'NNTF'):
            f = Gekko_NN_TF(model[1],model[2],m,1).predict([x1])

    m.Equation(x2.dt()==f)
    m.Obj(x2*final) # Objective function
    m.options.IMODE = 6 # optimal control mode
    m.solve(disp=False) # solve

    if plot:
        plt.figure(1) # plot results
        plt.plot(m.time,x1.value,'k-',label=r'$x_1$')
        plt.plot(m.time,x2.value,'b-',label=r'$x_2$')
        plt.plot(m.time,u.value,'r--',label=r'$u$')
        plt.legend(loc='best')
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Value')
        plt.show()
    if returns:
        return m.time,x1.value,x2.value,u.value

#Generate Training set
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 0.5*x**2

N = 200
xl = np.linspace(-2,2,N)
noise = np.random.normal(0,.1,N)
y_measured = f(xl) + noise

plt.plot(xl,f(xl),label='source function')
plt.plot(xl,y_measured,'.',label='measured points')
```

**Replace MPC with LSTM / Transformer**

[image: Emulation]

If using a TensorFlow LSTM model, you could just replace the entire MIMO MPC application as is shown in [Exercise 2](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/LSTMNetwork) as an Output-Input predictor. There is also a [SISO MPC and PID replacement example](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/LongShortTermMemory). Another option is to use the Transformer architecture instead of the LSTM (see [Transformer MPC GitHub archive](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/Transformer_MPC)) for improvements with vanishing gradients as the horizon time increases.

**Surrogate Model for MPC**

[image: Prediction]

If you want to use the LSTM model as an Input-Output predictor and wrap an optimizer, see this [code](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/Transformer_MPC/tree/main/02_Surrogate) that implements a [sequential shooting method](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/ModelPredictiveControl). I don't think there is a current way to use LSTMs in Gekko for MPC because it requires the gradients of the evaluation and LSTM models aren't supported yet. Additional information on functions that are supported are listed in the [Gekko documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! And also thank you for the multiple videos about GEKKO and model predictive control, they were very useful for my project.